# Picklable image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, multiprocessing

Does anyone know of a method to make images **picklable**? I am trying to pass OpenCV images between processes to separate display from real-time processing of an OpenCV video. I have tried **PIL** `Image.tostring()`, but to no avail. Is there a standard technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: [pickleable image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118068/pickleable-image-object)

Making it a dict and then using the information in the dict to recreate the image again. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's newer `cv2` module uses NumPy arrays, which are inherently pickleable. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054961/1510289